# Reverse IN function

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following table `teammessages`:

```
15:10 | Peter | I'm off to the store, call my mobile phone if you need me.
15:11 | Susy  | Have you seen the new scanner? It's lightning fast.
15:15 | Anne  | We have an emergency here, John broke the tap! Please switch off the water supply!
15:15 | John  | I did what?? :-D I'm in Vienna!
15:16 | Peter | I'm stuck in the elevator, help!
15:17 | Anne  | I said WATER, not POWER supply!
```

When I want to `SELECT` the urgent messages, containing key words like "help" or "emergency", from that chaotic freetext, I would have to have a "reverse IN" function, which doesn't check if the field is IN a given list of alternatives (`WHERE APPLECOLOR IN ('YELLOW', 'RED')`) but which checks if a value of the given alternatives is IN the field (`WHERE freetext REVERSE_IN ('help', 'emergency')`).

I've tried constructs like `WHERE freetext LIKE ('%help%' OR '%emergency%')`, but this gives me empty results.

**Clarification**: I can do this with `freetext LIKE ... OR freetext LIKE ... OR freetext LIKE ...` but it gets very long. So I am just looking for a shorthand like `IN` is in the "reverse case" (`APPLECOLOR = 'RED' OR APPLECOLOR = 'YELLOW'` <=> `APPLECOLOR IN ('RED', 'YELLOW')`).

Comment: It should be `WHERE freetext LIKE '%help%' OR  freetext LIKE '%emergency%'`

Comment: i would use Full-Text Search Functions ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html ) because `LIKE %help%` never can use indexes.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Seems like overkill here. An indexed computed column might be a better option, where the column only  needs to be searched at insert/update.

Comment: "An indexed computed column might be a better option" This is MySQL not SQL Server @JoelCoehoorn

Comment: @RaymondNijland MySql calls them generated columns. It's still a better solution.

Comment: "MySql calls them generated columns" i know i meant dont use a SQL Server term in a MySQL tagged topic  @JoelCoehoorn..

Answer (score 2):

The correct form of your original query is:

```
WHERE freetext LIKE '%help%' OR freetext LIKE '%emergency%'
```

However you might also like to consider using [`MATCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match). For that you will need to have a `FULLTEXT` index on the `message` column which you can add with this command:

```
ALTER TABLE teammessages ADD FULLTEXT INDEX(message);
```

You can then search using a query like this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM teammessages
WHERE MATCH(message) AGAINST('help emergency' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

which will give you better results than `LIKE`, which would also match words like 'whelp' or 'helpful' or 'helps'. In your sample table, this query returns:

```
time        name    message
15:15:00    Anne    We have an emergency here, John broke the tap! Please switch off the water supply!
15:16:00    Peter   I'm stuck in the elevator, help!
```

This query also has the advantage of not getting long as fast as multiple `LIKE`s

Comment: With the `FULLTEXT` index it should be as fast as multiple `LIKE`s, if not faster.

Comment: This looks promising!

Comment: Here's an article showing `FULLTEXT` search much faster than `LIKE`: https://makandracards.com/makandra/12813-performance-analysis-of-mysql-s-fulltext-indexes-and-like-queries-for-full-text-search

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a [Generated Column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html).

Answers involving `LIKE` are going to be **very slow** here, and answers involving full text search (`freetext`) expressions are telling MySql to index *every word* in the column, rather than just the words you care about.

You can use a generated column to produce a simple Y/N or 1/0 result for just the words you care about that only needs to evaluate the full column data at INSERT/UPDATE time.

Comment: This is a nice approach as well. :-)

Comment: " full text search expressions are telling MySql to index every word in the column" full text index does not index every word by the way.. common english words like `the` `some` are not indexed.. Besides you can make you own filter list.. Also you can control the minimal string length of words you want to index.. it is all in the documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html  and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the *words* help and emergency. You don't want to find

- Jake, your jokes are not helpful.
- You must subtract the tax. Hope this helps :-)

So check whether your version of MySQL supports regular expressions where you can look for words:

```
select *
from teammessages
where freetext regexp '[[:<:]](help|emergency)[[:>:]]';
```

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ILROPQ12660

Comment: What is `[[:<:]]`?

Comment: The beginning of a word. It has no length. It just indicates there is no letter or so before the word. (I.e. whelp wouldn't match because there is no beginning of a word before help.) `[[:>:]]` is the end of a word.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE freetext LIKE ('%help%' OR '%emergency%')` does not work like this.

It should be:

```
WHERE freetext LIKE '%help%' OR freetext LIKE '%emergency%'
```

**Additional:** From [documentation of LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) function:

> With LIKE you can use the following two wildcard characters in the
>   pattern:
>
> - % matches any number of characters, even zero characters.
> - _ matches exactly one character.

```
mysql> SELECT 'David!' LIKE 'David_';
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT 'David!' LIKE '%D%v%';
        -> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try :

```
WHERE freetext LIKE('%help%')  OR freetext LIKE('%emergency%')
```

Comment: So there is no short way (`IN` is a short way of multiple `OR`s as well)? In such a chaotic team, the list of key words would become very long.

Comment: yes but with in you check all the value ,you just want to match string containing help or emergency. You also can add a table with all your fields and check that table it will be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You could find all messages that are urgent with keywords you know by doing something similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM teammessages WHERE freetext LIKE '%help%' OR freetext LIKE '%emergency%';
```

You could do the 'reverse' of this by using `NOT LIKE` this way:

```
SELECT * FROM teammessages WHERE freetext NOT LIKE '%help%' AND freetext NOT LIKE '%emergency%';
```

Comment: No, sorry, I might have been unclear, I do not want to negate the search, I want to "reverse" the `IN`: Do not look if the field is IN my given alternatives, look if one of those alternatives is IN the field!

Comment: The top query gives results that are IN the list (messages containing help/emergency). The second query gives you a list (messages that do not contain the words help and emergency). If that is not what you mean, could you clarify a bit more in the question?